# Beginner Arduino loop function and variable

Tags: arduino

This is the revised code, the initial value is reading ridiculously high without the conversion!! How do I get the conversion to apply to the initialTemp as well temperatureC?

The code you have helped with as far as I can tell is exactly what I was trying to achieve, but obviously.

Thanks again!!

```
int pin_tempRead = 0;   // temperature sensor pin
int coolLED = 2; // cooling LED digital pin
int heatLED = 3; // heating LED digital pin
float initialTemp;
float cutOffTemp = 30; //cut off temperature = 30°C

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);  //Start the serial connection with the computer
  pinMode(heatLED, OUTPUT); //initialise as OUTPUT
  pinMode(coolLED, OUTPUT); //initialise as OUTPUT
  initialTemp = analogRead(pin_tempRead);   // read the initial temp
  Serial.print("Initial temperature: "); Serial.print(initialTemp); Serial.println("C"); //prints out starting temperature
}

void loop()                     // run over and over again
{
  //getting the voltage reading from the temperature sensor
  float current_temp = analogRead(pin_tempRead);

  // converting that reading to voltage
  float voltage = current_temp * 5.0; voltage /= 1024.0;

  float temperatureC = (voltage - 0.5) * 100 ;  //converting from 10 mv per degree with 500 mV offset
  //to degrees ((voltage - 500mV) times 100)

    if(temperatureC > cutOffTemp) {
        // temp too high -> turn on the cooling system
        digitalWrite(heatLED, LOW);
        digitalWrite(coolLED, HIGH);                          
    }else if (temperatureC < initialTemp) {
        // temp too low -> turn on the heating system
        digitalWrite(heatLED, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(coolLED, LOW);
    }
    Serial.print("Current pump temperature: ");
    Serial.print(temperatureC); Serial.println("C");
    delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `loop()` function executes over and over, so it's not a good place to store initial values.

What you need to do is define a global variable, initialize it inside the `setup()` function and then you can read it in the `loop()` function

Minimalist example:

```c
int pin_tempRead = 0;   // temperature sensor pin
float initial_temp;     // define a global variable

void setup() {
    initial_temp = analogRead(pin_tempRead);   // read the initial temp
}

void loop() {
    float current_temp = analogRead(pin_tempRead);
    // get the temperature difference respect to the initial one
    float difference = initial_temp - current_temp;
    delay(1000);
}
```

**PD:** Also is a good practice to distinguish the variables defining a hardware connection (pins) from the software ones. I usually append `pin_` to the variables that define connections. Otherwise is not clear if `tempRead` is the value of the temperature or the pin where the sensor is attached.

Also, for the turning on and off of the heater/cooling system: You are already in a loop (the `loop()` function is a loop) so you don't need a while loop.

And you have some problem with our logic.

As I understood, you want to heat until the higher threshold (cutOff) is reached, then cool down until the lower threshold is reached (initialTemperature).

This is called Hysteresis, but your logic was wrong, here's the corrected one:

Just do:

```c
void loop() {

    if(temperatureC > cutOffTemp) {
        // temp too high -> turn on the cooling system
        digitalWrite(heatLED, LOW);
        digitalWrite(coolLED, HIGH);                          
    }else if (temperatureC < initialTemp) {
        // temp too low -> turn on the heating system
        digitalWrite(heatLED, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(coolLED, LOW);
    }
    Serial.print("Current pump temperature: ");
    Serial.print(temperatureC); Serial.println("C");
    delay(1000);
}
```

By the way, you are using the initialTemperature as the low threshold for turning on the heating.

Is that what you really want?

What if the initial temperature is higher that the `cutOffTemp`? You will have problems in that case since the lower threshold is higher than the higher threshold.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! You have massively put me in the right direction. So what I want is the arduino to measure the temperature of a device, initially at room temperature, print out the initial reading. then print out a reading until it reaches 50°C (I picked 30°C as it is easy to trip the temp by hand) so in practice, the initial temp will never exceed the cut off temp. So what you have helped with works perfectly EXCEPT, the analog read without the voltage conversion to current temp displays the initial temp as 150+°C. I will edit my post with the new code. Thank you, thank you!!

Comment: I skipped all your convertion code. Take the answer as a skeleton code and add any code that you need.

Comment: So I moved the initial temp line to the void setup as I only need that printed once at the start. That's obviously where the error is occurring!

Comment: You never have both outputs LOW, which is different from doing nothing ...
If you really always wanted to have either Heating or Cooling active, you need only one output pin, but I cannot believe this.  ;)

Comment: True. But then it's another approach. You can have an optimal range where you have nothing on and a low and high threshold for turning on the heat and cool air on). But from the question looks like OP wants an hysteresis cycle with two thresholds and no optimal value.